# audio won't work on safari browser

Tags: html, audio, safari

could someone please help me to find out why this won't work on safari browser? It seems to work really well in all other browsers apart from Safari. I really could not work it out.

Any help will be most appreciated.

```js
function loadPlayer() 
 {
        var audioPlayer = new Audio();
        audioPlayer.controls="";
  audioPlayer.setAttribute("data-index", -1); //set default index to -1.
        audioPlayer.addEventListener('ended',nextSong,false);
        audioPlayer.addEventListener('error',errorFallback,true);
        document.getElementById("player").appendChild(audioPlayer);
    }
 
 
    function nextSong(index, e) 
 {
  var next;
  var audioPlayer = document.getElementsByTagName('audio')[0];
  //check for index. If so load from index. If not, index is defined auto iterate to next value.
  if (index >= 0)
  {
   next = index;
  }
  else
  {
   next = parseInt(audioPlayer.getAttribute("data-index"))+1;
   next >= urls.length ? next = 0 : null;
  }

  audioPlayer.src=urls[next][0]; //load the url.
  audioPlayer.setAttribute("data-index", next);
  //disable the player.
  var audioPlayerControls = document.getElementById("playerControls");
  audioPlayer.removeEventListener('canplay',enablePlayerControls,false);
  audioPlayerControls.setAttribute("disabled", true);
  audioPlayer.addEventListener('canplay',enablePlayerControls,false);
  audioPlayer.load();
  
  //show the image:
  var image = document.getElementById("playerList").querySelectorAll("a")[next].querySelector("img").cloneNode();
  image.style.width = "30px";
  if(audioPlayerControls.querySelector("img"))
  {
   audioPlayerControls.replaceChild(image, audioPlayerControls.querySelector("img"));
  }
  else
  {
   audioPlayerControls.insertBefore(image, audioPlayerControls.querySelector("a"));
  }
  
    }
 
 function enablePlayerControls()
 {
  //File has loaded, so we can start playing the audio. 
  //Enable the player options.
  var audioPlayer = document.getElementsByTagName('audio')[0];
  audioPlayer.removeEventListener('canplay',enablePlayerControls,false);
  document.getElementById("playerControls").removeAttribute("disabled");
  audioPlayer.play();
 }
 
    function errorFallback() {
        nextSong();
    }
 
 
    function playPause() 
 {
        var audioPlayer = document.getElementsByTagName('audio')[0];
  if (audioPlayer.paused) 
  {
   audioPlayer.play();
  } else 
  {
   audioPlayer.pause();
  }
    }
    function pickSong(e) 
 {
  //we want the correct target. Select it via the event (e).
  var target;
  
  //pickSong does the selecting:
  if (e && e.target && e.target.tagName && e.target.tagName.toLowerCase() == "img")
  {
        //The event target = the img element.
   target = e.target.parentElement;
  }
  else
  {
   //the event target is the a element
   target = e.target;
  }
  var index = target.getAttribute("data-index"); //get the song index stored in the data-index attribute.
        nextSong(index);
    }
 
    var urls = new Array();
    urls[0] = ['http://mp3lg4.tdf-cdn.com/9079/jet_143844.mp3', 'http://radio-maghreb.net/radio/radio almazighia.png'];
    urls[1] = ['http://mp3lg4.tdf-cdn.com/9077/jet_143651.mp3', "http://radio-maghreb.net/radio/alwatania.png"];
    urls[2] = ['http://mp3lg4.tdf-cdn.com/9080/jet_144136.mp3', "http://radio-maghreb.net/radio/inter.jpg"];
    

 function startAudioPlayer()
 {
  loadPlayer();
  for (var i = 0; i < urls.length; ++i)
  {
   //this for loop runs through all urls and appends them to the player list. This smooths the adding off new items. You only have
   //to declare them in the array, the script does the rest.
   var link = document.createElement("a");
   link.href = "javascript: void(0)";
   link.addEventListener("click", pickSong, false);
   link.setAttribute("data-index", i);
   link.img = document.createElement("img");
   link.img.src = urls[i][1];
   link.appendChild(link.img);
   document.getElementById("playerList").appendChild(link);
  }
 } 
 
    //Event that starts the audio player.
 window.addEventListener("load", startAudioPlayer, false);
```

```css
#playerControls[disabled=true] > a{
   color: #c3c3c3;
  }
```

```html
<span id="playerControls" disabled="true">
 <a href="javascript: void(0);" onclick="playPause()" id="player" title="Play">Play</a>
 <a href="javascript: void(0);" onclick="playPause()" id="player" title="Stop">Stop</a>
</span>
 <a href="javascript: void(0);" onclick="nextSong()" id="player" title="Next Station">Next Track</a>

<!-- player ends -->

<br>
<br>
<!-- img links start -->

<div id="playerList">

</div>
```

Comment: Hi @Mouser. could you please help me to find out why this won't work on safari browser? It seems to work really well in all other browsers apart from Safari. Any help will be most appreciated.